InsertPageBefore in view model in .NET MAUI app
In my .NET MAUI app, I have the following three pages in that particular hierarchy:
ReportsPage => SummaryPage => DetailPage
Up until now, the only way to get to the DetailPage was through the SummaryPage. I have now an interesting scenario where I have to create a direct way to get to the DetailPage from the ReportsPage i.e. ReportsPage => DetailPage.
With that said, I want to make sure I insert SummaryPage into the navigation stack. I understand I can achieve this with the following code:
await Shell.Current.Navigation.InsertBeforePage(new SummaryPage, this);
The problem I have is that all my pages have their own view models and I need to perform this operation in the view model for my DetailPage.
The second problem is that the SummaryPage expects navigation parameters i.e. ReportId.
How do I perform InsertBeforePage() in a view model AND also define the navigation parameter the SummaryPage is expecting?
I realize I can use the InsertBeforePage() in my view model but as I understand it, I need to refer to the current page using this i.e. Shell.Current.Navigation.InsertBeforePage(new SummaryPage(), this); and within the context of the view model this doesn’t refer to the current page.
All the examples I've found so far are fairly basic usage examples. I'd appreciate some pointers here. Thanks!

The simplest would be to navigate straight to the DetailsPage and insert the SummaryPage on the back stack, e.g.
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("SummaryPage/DetailPage");

As to propagating ReportId, I recommend setting that in a singleton view model that you CI/DI into both the ReportsPage and the DetailsPage so that the ReportsPage can set it, and the DetailsPage will receive it.
